# 2 video players - One in full screen, the other one in small (HTML CSS)

Tags: css

I have this template to load 2 players (local camera) (remote camera)

I'd like to know how make the remote in full screen (inside browser)
And the local camera in small

I've tried to change the css, but it changes for both players.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">


 <div class="row video-group">
     <div class="col">
       <p id="local-player-name" class="player-name"></p>
       <div id="local-player" class="player"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="w-100"></div>
     <div class="col">
       <div id="remote-playerlist"></div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

```
.player {
 width: 480px;
 height: 320px;
}

.player-name {
 margin: 8px 0;
}

#success-alert, #success-alert-with-token {
 display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
 .player {
   width: 320px;
   height: 240px;
 }
}
```

Comment: You can't have a full screen video playing with a normal video at the same time.